# Perl Getopt::Long module numeric values

Tags: perl

i need your help.

```
use Getopt::Long;
my $inputFile = "";
my $outputFile = "";
my $input_mm = ""; 
my $result;

$result = GetOptions (
                "fromFile=s" => \$inputFile,      # string
               "toFile=s"    =>  \$outputFile,
               "mm=i"     =>  \$input_mm);
```

in this case if in command line i give value to $input_mm  07  - perl sees it as 7. how do i fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=i` will read the value as a number.  If you want to preserve formatting, use `=s`.

After you read the value, if you want to make sure it's numeric, you can use `Scalar::Util`'s `looks_like_number` subroutine:

```
use Scalar::Util qw/looks_like_number/;

# ...

$result = GetOptions (
           "fromFile=s" => \$inputFile,      # string
           "toFile=s"    =>  \$outputFile,
           "mm=s"     =>  \$input_mm)
     or die("Error in command line arguments\n");

die "mm wasn't a number!" 
    unless defined $input_mm && looks_like_number($input_mm);
```

Also, don't forget to check the return code of GetOptions (per the Getopt:::Long docs); a false value means there were errors in reading the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use `=s` if you want to preserve the input value. You can check the validity of the value later e.g.

```
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
$result = GetOptions(...);
if (defined $input_mm) {
     looks_like_number($input_mm) or die "Invalid mm value '$input_mm'";
}
```

Comment: right. i didnt think think of that. thank you.  it does the job for me.   just out of curiosity, if i need this to be numberic value and it starts from 0, what would i be doing? its not important, just for learning sake.

Answer (score -1):

In the GetOptions method, it take the parameter =i as a number, if you want to make it as the number, you should use the function 
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number)

Comment: looks_like_number doesn't "make" a value a number; it tells you whether or not Perl will be able to interpret it as a number.